# ArcSDE - where to start?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, sql-server

As I long ago figured out that I need more complex query-asking abilities (other than the standard select provided by arcgis), and as I will someday have to admin a small scale SDE database that will import data from my corporate's big and country-wide SDE, I wanted to set up a small workgroup SDE on a standalone computer so I could deal with it a bit, to get the hang of dealing with a sde.

But where do I start? I can't find a good manual to start with - The Arcgis 9.3.1 Help(on which I'm working) isn't much help. I know I need to Install SQL server, but I can't understand any of the other steps (creation, import of data and such).

Do you know of any good guides and resources to guide me with the arcgis 9.3.1 SDE from scratch?

(Oh, and does SDE 10 differ a lot from SDE 9.3.1?)

Comment: On a 64 bit machine I had problems configuring arcsde for sql server64.  I ended up uninstalling 64bit sqlserver and re-installing x86, then was able to configure arcsde.

Comment: I also have some problems with 64 bit sql server 2008. It gives me random errors while loading, inserting and editing and some others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have a few mins now so.. I'll provide a starting link.  Better than that I will show you the navigation.  If you go to resources.arcgis.com and navigate to help (at the top) find the desktop help> 9.3 & 9.3.1

In the tree you will see geodatabases and arcsde. Lots of good information there.

[OK OK](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=welcome)

Also a tutorial pdf can be found [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/pdf/DatabaseServers_Tutorial.pdf)

There are differences in 10 and 9.3.1.

It is not clear if you meant you be installing  arcgis server workgroup sde or the sde personal (on your desktop).
Sorry but sde personal doesn't have the commandline administration (or much admin at all for that matter) that you may be looking for to get "aquainted".

If you are installing AGS (SDE) Jump In! it's not as scary as it may seem.
And if you have a standalone machine (not corporate data) plan on messing it up and starting over a couple of times.
It goes a lot faster the third time through. Plus you will start to see some workflow issues that you would have had to hire someone to tell you about.

I'll be back later to fill in some more.

Answer (score 1):

The help documentation is going to be your best friend as you start digging into SDE. Most of the info you'll need is there, it's just a matter of finding it. Here are some links to get you started:

- [What is ArcSDE](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_ArcSDE/000500000001000000/)
- [A quick tour of administering ArcSDE geodatabases](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_administering_ArcSDE_geodatabases/000500000002000000/)
- [Essential ArcSDE geodatabase vocabulary](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Essential_ArcSDE_geodatabase_vocabulary/000500000003000000/)

As for differences between 9.3.1 and 10, there are a few but the core concepts have not changed and if you're comfortable with 9.3.1, it shouldn't be too much trouble to move to 10. For specifics, check out the [What's new for geodatabases in ArcGIS 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_s_new_for_geodatabases/00qp0000000v000000/) document for changes that 10 brought.

To get started with ArcSDE Workgroup Geodatabases, go here:  [What are database servers in ArcGIS?](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_are_database_servers_in_ArcGIS/003n0000004r000000/). That topic is helpful, but more importantly, it gets you in the workgroup SDE part of the help documentation tree.